# Frequency discrepancy: harmonically forced, Undamped, mass-spring system

Tags: differential-equations, vibrations, linear-systems

I got an undamped mass-spring system:

\begin{equation}
{\frac { {d} ^{2}y}{ {d} t^{2}}}+4\pi^{2}y=0.0942*(0.0227 - 0.236*\sin(5.0631 - 2\pi*2t))
\end{equation}

where $y$ is displacement. The two boundary conditions: 
\begin{equation}
y(t=99.9997077)=-3.6060801,\ \ \ \ 
\frac{dy}{dt}(t=99.9997077)=0.11944709
\end{equation}

I used Matlab to solve this ODE: However, the solved out displacement $y(t)$ has a frequency $f=1$, but we can see the term $- 2\pi*2t$ in the equation, which means the input force has a frequency of $f=2$.

On the other hand, it seems that with the harmonic force on a linear mass-spring system, the displacement should have **Identical frequency**.

So could you help me to double check my result? I have checked many times that my Matlab coding should be alright, but the results seem against the theory.

So am I using the wrong theory or I made a mistake while solving the ODE?

Appreciate any help.

======================

Edit 1:
I tried several frequencies already, but the solved out displacement always has a frequency of $f=1$.

Comment: Note that the undriven frequency of your mass-spring system is $f = 1$. What's probably going on is that your driving force really does contribute a $f = 2$ oscillation, but it's much smaller than the $f = 1$ contribution from the initial conditions. To test this, try rerunning with boundary conditions $y = y' = 0$.

Comment: Also, consider making some of the numbers nicer -- it just makes it harder to read the question.

Comment: @knzhou thanks I will think about it. The weired number is to model the experimental results I obtain, but yes maybe should make it simpler.

Comment: Dear @knzhou : so I guess if the system is damped, the vibration frequency will then eventually reach the driver's frequency due to the dissipation of energy? You may just answer the question as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WolframAlpha generates the following solution to your differential equation.

[image]

The dominant term has a frequency of 1 Hz and it swamps the 2 Hz term.

Answer (score 0):

More [solution by WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27%27(t)%2B4pi%5E2*y(t)%3DB%2BA*sin(w*t-phi)):

[image]